# Random no generation Vs Hashing inside a kernel

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

Concerning some random no. generation I have choices as follows:

1- Generate Random nos. on GPU and use in Kernel

2- Generate Random nos. on CPU and send in Kernel via PCI-e

3- Generate random nos using Hashing function written inside the kernel

How do I decide which  is best one ? Any general guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

Choice 1 should be the best. CUDA provides cuRAND library to generate random numbers of various distributions. It's designed to have best performance.

Choice 2 has relatively poor performance. This figure shows the performance gap between GPU and CPU on random number generation.

[image: cuRAND v.s. MKL]

Choice 3 is unnecessary because you are trying to re-implement cuRAND library with this approach.

Please refer to cuRAND homepage and doc for more details.

https://developer.nvidia.com/curand

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html